# Angular center modal

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having troubles centering bootstrap modal in Angular. All other questions seem outdated. I have the following modal:

```
<ng-template #changeIncome>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Income</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="number" #amountDashboard id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control" required="required">
                <div id="amm"></div><br />
                <input type="number" #dateDashboard id="date" name="date" class="form-control" required="required">
                <div id="dat"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" (click)="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

I would like a modal with class modal-dialog-centered in order to get it centered, but I don't see a way to do it. Any ideas?
I am using ngx-bootstrap/modal

Comment: Can you show the code of ts component?

Comment: You mean having the modal centered vertically right?

Comment: That is correct.